# Mapping a numerical array of numbers onto the surface of f(x,y) possible?

Tags: plotting, textures

I'm considering mapping an error estimate matrix onto the surface of a function f(x,y) in the indicated range:

```
theF[x_, y_] = -1.295 + y (-0.1098 - 0.43 Log[x]) - 2.36 Log[x]
Plot3D[theF[x, y], {x, 0.056, 0.83}, {y, 50, 508}, PlotRange -> All, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

For a matrix of points in the plot range, there is an error matrix assigning to each point, a corresponding non-negative error code:

```
errorTable = {{8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {7, 6, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1}, {7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {6, 5, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}};
```

The dimension of errorTable is {10,25}  and as an example, can just use a random matrix:

```
errorTable = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 8}], {10}, {25}]
```

For example, in the matrix above errorTable[[1,1]]=8 and that corresponds to the error for the point (x,y)=(0.056,50) and so forth.  I know how to create an `ArrayPlot` and color the error codes and then map this plot as a texture to the surface of f:

```
theF[x_, y_] = -1.295 + y (-0.1098 - 0.43 Log[x]) - 2.36 Log[x]
ap = ArrayPlot[errorTable, 
   ColorRules -> {-1 -> Red, 0 -> Black, 1 -> Blue, 2 -> Green, 
     3 -> Yellow, 4 -> Purple, 5 -> Orange, 6 -> White, 7 -> Magenta, 
     8 -> Pink}];

 cPlot = Plot3D[
  theF[x, y], {x, Abs[aVals[[1]]], Last@Abs[aVals]}, {y, 50, 
   seriesSize}, Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {Texture[ap]}, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And I could add a legend but it's not quickly comprehensible and confussing-looking.  Is there a way to map the error matrix numbers directly onto F in a clear and easy to read way and if so could someone help me do this?

Comment: @Michael E2:  Don't understand your question.  I mean to write the numbers on the surface of f(x,y) but not just write graphics numbers over the corresponding point (x,y,z) but rather write the numbers as a texture onto the surface?

Comment: @Michael E2:  Ok.  I meant map onto the surface of f(x,y).  Changed title.

Answer (score 12):

Via `MeshShading` and `Texture`:

```
theF[x_, y_] = -1.295 + y (-0.1098 - 0.43 Log[x]) - 2.36 Log[x];
pp = Plot3D[theF[x, y], {x, 0.056, 0.83}, {y, 50, 508}, 
   PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
   Mesh -> Reverse@Dimensions@errorTable - 1,
   MeshShading -> Reverse@errorTable,
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> (Evaluate[
       Reverse@Dimensions@errorTable {#1, #2}] &)];

pp /. {a___, n_, g_GraphicsGroup, b___} :> {a, 
   Texture[Rasterize[n, ImageSize -> 400]], g, b}
```

[image]

---

*Update: Via MaTeX*

```
(* ResourceFunction["MaTeXInstall"][] (* if needed *)*)
Needs@"MaTeX`"
pp /. {a___, n_, g_GraphicsGroup, b___} :>
 {a, Texture[MaTeX[n]], g, b}
```

[image]

*Update 2: Color*

Replace `MaTeX[n]` by something like one of the following to color the surface.

```
Show[MaTeX[n], Background -> GrayLevel[0.5 + n/16]]
Show[MaTeX[n], Background -> Lighter@ColorData["Rainbow"][n/8]]
```

I'd also recommend `Lighting -> "Neutral"` in original `Plot3D`, so that the colors of the lights don't affect the colors on the surface.

Comment: Can speed it up a little with`mem : memRasterize[expr_] := mem = Rasterize[expr, ImageSize -> 400]` and `memRasterize[n]` instead of `Rasterize[...]`

Comment: Your mem code dropped the timing from about 20 seconds to one second on my machine.  Nice improvement!  It looks nice.   Didn't think this was possible.  Thank you.

Comment: @josh ``MaTeX`` does not need the memoization, since it caches its results automatically.

Comment: The MaTex version looks publish-quality!  Appreciate your work.  Will set  a bounty when eligible.

Comment: I appreaciate your help in this matter.  I chose ImportString below for the bounty because it's simple and fast.

Comment: @josh No problem. As I pointed out in my comment, `pic = Rasterize[grid]` is faster and just as good, if the image is going to be exported out of Mathematica into TeX (or other). (I'm a math person, and one shortcoming I have is preferring "exact" over "good enough." And the grid is good enough. I also like how the TeX would fit better the style of a paper, and it's slowness is negligible compared to the time one puts into a paper. That's also why I excluded my ImportString version. And three ways seemed overkill, when the PDF and MaTeX are doing virtually the same thing except for the font.)

Answer (score 5):

Use `Grid` and export it to `"PNG"`.

```
theF[x_, y_] = -1.295 + y (-0.1098 - 0.43 Log[x]) - 2.36 Log[x];
errorTable = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 8}], {10}, {25}];
grid = Grid[errorTable, Frame -> All, 
   ItemStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, 20}];
(* pic=ImportString[ExportString[grid,"PNG"]] *)
pic = First[
  ImportString[ExportString[grid, "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, 
   "TextOutlines" -> True]]
Plot3D[theF[x, y], {x, 0.056, 0.83}, {y, 50, 508}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Texture[pic], Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and compact.  Takes 1.2 seconds on my machine!  The numbers are very clear and readable and even though the random matrix looks confussing, in my application there is a distinct distribution, like above example, which is almost instantly comprehended when viewed and that is my desire without the need to make some mental color-conversion.  Thank you!

Comment: +1 but why not just use `pic = Rasterize[grid]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks! I also test the `Rasterize` approach. But I also want to test whether the texture suport vector format such as`PDF`,that is when we use `pic = First[ImportString[ExportString[grid, "PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, 
   "TextOutlines" -> True]]`. So I post the above code.

Comment: Did it support vector graphics? I tried it and it seemed not to work. But maybe there's a way around. (MaTeX produces vector graphics, too, which it why I tried it.)

Answer (score 3):

Adding these lines after the definition of `errorTable` in the previous answers keeps both the colors (showing the distribution) and the numbers.

```
colors = <|-1 -> Red, 0 -> Black, 1 -> Blue, 2 -> Darker@Green, 
   3 -> Gray, 4 -> Purple, 5 -> Orange, 6 -> Brown, 7 -> Magenta, 
   8 -> Pink|>;
errorTable = errorTable /. a_Integer :> Style[a, colors[[Key[a]]]];
```

[image]